# Fiter an array based on a Binary Search Tree-like algorithm

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I have a sorted array of dates like this :

`let arr = ['2019-03-12', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-09', '2018-06-09', '2018-01-24', ..]`

This `arr` is of length **100,000**, so it is asked to filter this array based on **binary search tree** (due to performance considerations). But I cannot understand how? since binary search tree returns an exact value but I want to return all the values that includes 2018, for example.
Any clue how can I implement this?

Comment: You can use a binary search to find the indexes of the first and last values that are in 2018, then take that slice (from first to last) of the array.

Comment: Check the implementation of lowerBound function [here](https://github.com/felipernb/algorithms.js/blob/master/src/algorithms/search/binarysearch.js). You can use similar approach to find the upperBound/right-most index of the element in O(log N).

Comment: you can hash by year if you want to return all values by year.

Comment: @VighneshRaut would you please help me with the upperBound too? I'm getting wrong results.

Comment: @D.Seah It's not just year. I want to filter it based on any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `upperBound` and `lowerBound` binary search.

Upper Bound gives the index of the last occurrence of an element in a sorted array.

```js
const upperBound = (sortedArray, element) => {
  let lo = 0;
  let hi = sortedArray.length - 1;

  let rightMost = -1;

  while (lo <= hi) {
    const mid = ((hi - lo) >> 1) + lo;
    
    if (sortedArray[mid] === element) {
      rightMost = Math.max(rightMost, mid);
    }

    if (sortedArray[mid] >= element) {
      lo = mid + 1;
    } else {
      high = mid - 1;
    }
  }

  return rightMost;
};
```

For the lowerBound, or left most occurrence of a number in a sorted array, you can use this:

```js
const lowerBound = (sortedArray, element) => {
  let lo = 0;
  let hi = sortedArray.length - 1;

  while (lo <= hi) {
    const mid = ((hi - lo) >> 1) + lo;
    if (sortedArray[mid] > element) {
      hi = mid - 1;
    } else {
      lo = mid + 1;
    }
  }

  return lo;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned a `binary search` will get you a single value from a collection. What you can simply do in this case is, you can splice the values returned from your `binary search` and repeat until there is no element that includes 2018.

> *The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s).*

And of course, you'll need to store the returned values.

```js
let arr = ['2019-03-12', '2019-02-11', '2019-02-09', '2018-06-09', '2018-01-24', '2018-01-24'];

    arr.sort();
    let filteredArr = [];
    let result = 0;
    while (result !== -1) {
       result = bSearch(arr, '2018');
       if (result !== -1) {
          filteredArr.push(arr[result]);
          arr.splice(result, 1);
       }
    }
    // Your filtered array
    console.log(filteredArr)

    function bSearch(arr, x) { 
        let start=0, end=arr.length-1; 
        while (start <= end){
            let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
            // If element is present at mid, return index 
            if (arr[mid].substring(0,4) === (x)) return mid; 
            else if (arr[mid] < x)
                 start = mid + 1; 
            else
                 end = mid - 1;
        } 
        return -1; 
    }
```